# How to run Camera as a background service not in main thread(background thread) in andoid

Tags: android, service, android-intentservice, android-background, jobintentservice

How to create camera as background service which should be run in other than main thread.
When am trying to run through thread handler getting crashed due to `windgowmanager` which required UI thread. How can i resolve this issue

Comment: post the code where you are trying to complete this action

Comment: Do you want to take a photo without the user knowing? If you show the camera's UI you have to run it from the main UI thread.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo yes i want to take a photo without the user knowing but that should not run on mainthread. Do you have any references for that.

Comment: not sure whether that works but I remember seeing this example in the past: https://github.com/botyourbusiness/android-camera2-secret-picture-taker